# The scala plugin for IDEA 12.x not working as expected with akka

Tags: java, scala, maven, intellij-idea, akka

I am trying to use akka with maven and scala and I have added the akka actor jars to my pom.

Now in IDEA I go ahead and type this up,

```
class HelloWorld extends Actor {

}
```

At this point it correctly highlights HelloWorld as in error. I try to fix the errors and it correctly says that I have unimplemented methods (receive). I say go ahead and add the method and it does nothing.

I am using 
IDEA 12.1.6 
Scala plugin 0.22.302
Mac OSX 10.9.2

Note that if I created a trait myself

```
trait MyTrait {
  def foo : Void
}
```

and tried to implement it like so

```
class MyImpl extends MyTrait {
}
```

Then I am correctly prompted for methods to be added and it does add the methods when I say go ahead.

Comment: Are you trying to extend `Akka` actors class ? beware scala also has got Actors

Comment: Yes I am aware. I failed to mention that I did have to import akka.actor.Actor

Comment: I also experienced this kind of behaviour (on other classes, not actors), anyway it works for me on `IDEA` with version `0.36.431` of the Scala  plugin.

Comment: Ende Neu which version of IDEA are you using?

Comment: `13.1`, but my guess is that the problem is related to the Scala plugin version, oldest versions had a very long list of problems and your version is pretty old, not adding unimplemented methods should be the least of it.

Comment: I suspect that the new version of the scala plugin is not compatible with version 12 of IDEA. I am installing IDEA 13 to see if I can get the new version of the scala plugin with it and if it solves the problem.

Comment: I am using 13.1.3 EAP and its very good (scala plugin is better).

Comment: Using 13.1 with the new scala plugin 0.36.431 does solve my problem - Thanks!